C enum implementing from_str and to_str functions? - Maybe an X-macro?
Given trivial typedef-free ANSI C code, how does one implement an X-macro to define everything in one place?
enum Foo {
    CAN, BAR, UNKNOWN
};

const char *Foo_to_str(enum Foo foo) {
    switch (foo) {
        case CAN:
            return "Can";
        case BAR:
            return "Bar is here";
        case UNKNOWN:
        /* `default:` like to keep this commented 
           out so compiler warns that case is missed */
            return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}


enum Foo Foo_from_str(const char *s) {
    if (strcmp(s, "Can")) return CAN;
    else if (strcmp(s, "Bar is here")) return BAR;
    else return UNKNOWN;
}

I started to mess around with arrays but not sure if I would be better served by a {{FOO, "Foo"}} style array, also I don't need the actual array so not sure if that's a good approach anyway:
#define FOOX \
  X(FOO, "Foo") \
  X(BAR, "Bar is here")

enum Foo{
#define X(_, N) N,
  FOOX
#undef X
};

char const *const FooA[] = {
#define X(N, _) #N,
    FooE
#undef X
};


const char* Foo_to_str(enum FooE foo) {
  return FooA[foo];
}

(would be great to separate interface and implementation in a header and source; but that might be a little ambitious considering macro usage)

What should Foo_from_str() return if both compares fail?  Leave as UB?

I was going to add a default final enum discriminant value of UNKNOWN. - EDIT: Added that.

@AT C does not check if passed value is correct. It is still UB

#define X(N, _) #N Here you are making an array of the name parameter converted to a string, rather than returning the provided string. That is "BAR" rather than "Bar is here". Other than that the code looks mostly ok.
I would recommend to use this style:
#define FOO_LIST(X)       \
  /*name, str */          \
  X(FOO,  "Foo")          \
  X(BAR,  "Bar is here")

Passing the X as macro parameter removes the need to define some mysterious X all over the place and later #undef it. Instead you can create situation-specific macros with unique names. Another advantage with this style is that if you have multiple X macro list data sets with the same parameters, you could reuse those situation-specific macros across multiple lists.
A complete example would be something like this:
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO_LIST(X)       \
  /*name, str */          \
  X(FOO,  "Foo")          \
  X(BAR,  "Bar is here")

enum Foo {
  #define FOO_ENUM(name, str) name,
  FOO_LIST(FOO_ENUM)

  FOO_N,          // number of items in the enum
  FOO_ERROR = -1  // some error code
};

const char* const FooA[] = {
  #define FOO_STR(name, str) str,
  FOO_LIST(FOO_STR)
};

const char* Foo_to_str(enum Foo f) {
  return FooA[f];
}

enum Foo Foo_from_str(const char* s) {
  /* 
    This is a naive search algorithm calling strcmp repeatedly in a
    nested list of ?: operators, ending with a -1 if nothing was found.
  */
  #define FOO_STRCMP(name, str) (strcmp(str,s)==0) ? name : 
  return FOO_LIST(FOO_STRCMP) FOO_ERROR;
}

int main()
{
  puts(Foo_to_str(FOO));
  puts(Foo_to_str(BAR));

  printf("%d\n", Foo_from_str("Foo"));
  printf("%d\n", Foo_from_str("Bar is here"));
  printf("%d\n", Foo_from_str("Bad input"));
}


You could do something like this
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Put the strings in alphabetical order */
#define FOOX \
  X(BAR, "Bar is here") \
  X(FOO, "Foo")

/* Define the enum */
enum FooE{
#define X(N, _) N,
  FOOX
#undef X
  /* this is how many you have */
  FooE_Max,
  /* Return this value when the string cannot be found */
  FooE_NOT_FOUND
};

/* Define the strings */
char const *const FooA[] = {
#define (_, N) N,
    FOOX
#undef X
    ""
};

const char* Foo_to_str(enum FooE foo) {
  return FooA[foo];
}

/* Bsearch needs FooA to be in alpha order */
enum FooE Foo_from_str(const char* str) {
   enum FooE* rv = bsearch(str, FooA, FooE_Max, sizeof(const char*), strcmp);
   return rv == NULL? FooE_NOT_FOUND: *rv;
}

Note that bsearch will only work when the list of strings is sorted.
